# TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [0.0] of <class 'float'>

Tags: python, streamlit

this my code use streamlit

```
def main():

st.title(
    'Aplikasi Forecasting Exchange Rate')

def file_selector(folder_path='./datasets'):

    filenames = os.listdir(folder_path)
    selected_filename = st.selectbox("Select A file", filenames)
    return os.path.join(folder_path, selected_filename)

filename = file_selector()
st.info("Kamu memilih {}".format(filename))

# Read Data
dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates,'%d-%m-%y')
akhir = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=[0], date_parser=dateparse)
akhir['Terakhir'] = akhir['Terakhir'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)

# Show Dataset
if st.checkbox("Show Dataset"):
    number = st.number_input("Number of Rows to View")
    st.dataframe(akhir.head(number))
```

and i got error when i want to show dataset
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on  with these indexers [0.0] of

Comment: `number` is probably a float. What happens if you cast it to `int`?

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the default for `number_input` uses a step size of 0.01 and you aren't specifying any of the function arguments, which implies a float is returned.

To fix your code:

```
number = st.number_input("Number of Rows to View", min_value = 0, step = 1)
```

https://docs.streamlit.io/en/latest/api.html#streamlit.number_input